# Magento 1.8.0.1 newsletter Sent, no error reports but recipients not receiving the newsletter

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

So as it says, I create newsletter, queue the newsletter, process it and the newsletter has a Sent message, recipients increase to the subscriber number.
I have checked the Newsletter error tab and the exception log but there is nothing telling me it's failed yet none of the newsletters are received by any of the subscribers.
Any ideas on what might be causin the problem or how to test it further, maybe even a fix ;)

Thanks for your time great people of Stack Overflow :)

Comment: It seems like a mail error. Perhaps a firewall is blocking it because SPF/MX records are incorrect. (Would be my guess if magento isnt reporting errors.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to reply.  Odd thing is that all other emails get sent out.  New subscriptions, sales invoices and so on so I would assume that a firewall issue would also block these?

Comment: It would seem that way. It is worth ruling it out if you are unsure. newsletters tend to be the 'spammyer' type.

Comment: mmm, something funny going on as the server is running mail() fine but if i run a simple mail script it returns an error saying it cant send it...  very odd indeed.

Comment: @TonyPollard Try to check apache log as well as Magento logs

Comment: Are you using PHP mail? Try some SMTP service and install that.

Comment: Hey Matt, you beat me too it actually.  I have been playing with this for a couple of days and yes, setting Magento to send mail using SMTP worked.  Thanks for your time and suggestions, appreciated.